# ZMQ Socket solution for a 1-to-1 two-way communication with connection re-establishment?

Tags: sockets, zeromq

I'm looking for a ZMQ-capable solution for a communication between an bound endpoint that is connected to 0 or 1 peers and no more than that. The communication is two-way, and the connection can be ended or severed at any point in time; and the connection can be re-establish with either a new peer or the same peer. It doesn't matter if the bound endpoint blocks or doesn't block if it doesn't have a peer on the other side.

What ZMQ socket pair would suit this use case the best? I was initially thinking REP/REQ, but the socket pair allows for multiple REQs to connect to one REP, which I don't want; it also will need to handle the "I'm waiting for a recv/I'm going to send something" lockstep paradigm when someone disconnects. PAIR also seems bad because it doesn't naturally handle the reconnect, but it has the "0 or 1 peer" restriction I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: Unfortunately there isn't a pattern that exactly fits your needs out of the box.

The closest pattern is the [ZMQ PAIR to PAIR pattern](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-socket). However it has some limitations in the following ways:

> ZMQ_PAIR sockets are designed for inter-thread communication across
>   the zmq_inproc(7) transport and do not implement functionality such as
>   auto-reconnection. ZMQ_PAIR sockets are considered experimental and
>   may have other missing or broken aspects.

ROUTER and DEALER is the most flexible pattern. You can control it to set the restrictions you need.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too up for re-implementing autoreconnection logic, so I feel like using DEALER/REQ and then using the Identity stuff to build some exclusive-lock mechanism. Thanks for your help.